# Unable to access variable outside of query function even though variable is declared after class

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a few queries running to load variables with data from a Parse server into variables that are declared right below class. When I print the variable to the console within the query function, it prints correctly, but when I call it outside of the function or print it, it is empty. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Variable declaration:

```
class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
var varCost = ""
```

Query loading variable:

```
let varCostQuery = PFQuery(className: "Class1")
varCostQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        varCostQuery.whereKey("Header", equalTo: self.HeaderSelection.text)
        varCostQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            for object in objects! {
                self.varCost = object["pricePerUnit"] as! String
                print(self.varCost) //Option1
            }
        })
    }
})
print(varCost) //Option2
```

When I print Option1, I get the data exactly like I'm looking for, but when I print Option2 or try to do anything with the `varCost` variable at this level, I get `""` like the variable has never been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the code being passed to the `findObjectsInBackground` method is code that is run **only** once all the objects have been found.

Because this code will only be called when the objects have been found, this may take a bit of time, so this code is send to a background queue to wait for the objects to be found.

We don't want the rest of our code to pause and wait for this though! That would slow our program down a lot. So the program continues past this block until it completes. That's why *Option 2* is empty, because `findObjectsInBackground` hasn't had time to get the objects yet so the code has jumped straight to where *Option 2* is.

When the objects have finally been found, the block of code is called and *Option 1* is printed.

This means that you can only be sure `self.varCost` will have the right value from within this block (or *closure*, as it is called in Swift).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Any recommendation how to fix it? I could put a 1 second pause in after the final query to give it time to make the change and it probably wouldn't affect UX too much but I'd be happy to consider better options.

Comment: @tmcgee Putting in a 1 second pause wouldn't be good practice, because we have no idea how long this object finding is going to take. It would be better to call a function with `self.varCost` as a parameter from inside the block, so you can do whatever you like with `self.varCost` from within this function, and you are **100% sure** it is the correct value.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example? Sounds like a much better approach than a static pause. I've tried putting a pause in just to see if I could get it to solve the issue temporarily and it's still pushing "" on print. :/